# SQL Server find week number of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for tracking back on earlier posts. I'm trying to calculate week number in month, and as in other posts using

```
select datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, @date) / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1
```

This works fine in most cases but falls over where the first Monday in the month falls on the 7th. For example

```
select datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, '06-sep-2020') / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1  -
```

correctly returns 5 for August week 5 since the monday of that week was in August (31st)

```
select datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, '07-sep-2020') / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1
```

incorrectly returns 2 for what should be Week 1 of September.

Same issue seen in December 2020 where first Monday falls on 7th.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please define what YOU mean by the week number in the month.

Comment: Is your meaning of week number 1 is that it is the first occurrence of a particular day within the month?  Or are you thinking that week 1 is any day that would appear on the top row of days when modeling the month with the dates as 7 columns where Sunday is the leftmost column?  Perhaps you could try to design a query that would output the dates in result rows in the same format and then use rownum() to represent the week number?  Might also need to use pivot to get the dates into the columns.

Comment: September 7 being monday falls on week 2 only. Why it should be week 1 ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR because this code calculates week numbers as 7 day blocks from the 1st of a month. 1-Sep-2020 is a Tuesday and 7-Sep-2020 is the first Monday, but this code says it is still "Week 1." If that blows your mind have a read through ISO 8601 and see how it calculates week numbers based on which years Thursdays fall in.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for clarifying

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. So our rule is that weeks start on a Monday. So whenever the first Monday falls is Week 1 of the month. In the example ive used the previous Monday ia August 31st - this is the 5th Monday of August and so week commencing August 5th is correctly returned as Week5. To Summarise, using the sql above,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to derive the prior Monday and check which week that Monday is in

```
DECLARE @TestDate DATE = '06-sep-2020';
SELECT FLOOR((datepart(day,CASE 
    WHEN datepart(WEEKDAY,@TestDate) = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY,-6, @TestDate) 
    ELSE DATEADD(DAY,2-datepart(WEEKDAY,@TestDate), @TestDate)
    END)-1)/7) +1 as NewWeekNum
```

If you want to test it on a bunch of values, put them in this test harness, I checked a bunch and all seemed to meet your criteria.

```
;with cteTestDates as (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,Test) as DateTest 
    FROM (VALUES('06-sep-2020'), ('07-sep-2020')
        , ('07-dec-2020')) as Dates(Test)
)SELECT * 
    , datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, DateTest) / 7 * 7) / 7 + 1 as OldWeekNum
    , FLOOR((datepart(day,CASE 
        WHEN datepart(WEEKDAY,DateTest) = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY,-6, DateTest) 
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY,2-datepart(WEEKDAY,DateTest), DateTest) 
        END)-1)/7) +1 as NewWeekNum
FROM cteTestDates
```